# array_combine multiple $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have this code:

```
foreach (array_combine($_SESSION['prod'], $_SESSION['pid']) as $prod => $pid) 
{
    echo    'od_no: '.$prod.' - '.'prod_id: '.$pid.'<br>';              
}
```

I also want to include in the `foreach` loop the value of another session, `$_SESSION['so']`. How can I do that?

Comment: Do all those values have the same array size?

Comment: @Jack, yes they're all the same array size.

Comment: @Jack, oops. I thought OP wanted value in another session...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all arrays have the same size and elements at the same index are related:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['prod'] as $k => $prod) {
    $pid = $_SESSION['pid'][$k];
    $so = $_SESSION['so'][$k];
    // rest of your code
}
```